# Primefaces tabView activeIndex property is always getting null

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf-2, primefaces

Primefaces tabView activeIndex property  is always getting null.

My view.jsf:

```
<h:form>
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
<p:tabView >
<p:ajax event="myForm" listener="#{employeeEdit.onTabChange}" /> 
<p:tab id="basic" title="Login">
</p:tab>
<p:tab id="personal" title="Personal">
</p:tab>
<p:tab id="contact" title="Contact">
</p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

My edit.jsf:

```
<h:form prependId="false" >
<p:tabView id="myid" activeIndex="#{employeeEdit.tabIndex}" >
<p:tab id="basic" title="Login">
</p:tab>
<p:tab id="personal" title="Personal">
</p:tab>
<p:tab id="contact" title="Contact">
</p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Backing bean:
EmployeeEdit.java:

```
@Component("employeeEdit")
@ViewScoped
@Repository
public class EmployeeEdit implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2784529548783517864L;
    private EmployeeDTO employeeDTO = new EmployeeDTO();
    public static HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
    private int tabIndex;   

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        System.out.println("in SessionFactory" +sessionFactory);
        this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
        System.out.println("in SessionFactory" +hibernateTemplate);

    }


    public int onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {   

        System.out.println("tab id = " + event.getTab().getId()+event.getTab().getTitle());
        if(event.getTab().getId().equals("personal"))
        {
            tabIndex =0;
        }
        else if(event.getTab().getId().equals("address"))
        {
            tabIndex =1;
        }
        else
        {
            tabIndex =2;
        }
        System.out.println("tabIndex = "+tabIndex);
        return tabIndex;
    }



    public void edit() throws IOException
    {

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/employeeedit.jsf");
    }



    public void cancel() throws IOException
    {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/employeelist.jsf");
    }

    public EmployeeDTO getEmployeeDTO() {
        return employeeDTO;
    }

    public void setEmployeeDTO(EmployeeDTO employeeDTO) {
        this.employeeDTO = employeeDTO;
    }

    public int getTabIndex() {
        return tabIndex;
    }

    public void setTabIndex(int tabIndex) {
        this.tabIndex = tabIndex;
    }
}
```

But always getting tabIndex=0; Why this happening? The AJAX is working fine. But on clicking the Edit button in the view page tabIndex is getting null.
in view.jsf, my command button is

```
<p:commandButton value="Edit" actionListener="#{employeeEdit.edit}" />
```

**My primefaces version is: primefaces-3.0.M3 with Google Cloud SQL**

Comment: Can you post the whole managed bean (`EmployeeEdit`)? Right now you have only posted the part that you say is working.

Comment: What happens if you make your `EmployeeEdit` `@SessionScoped`?

Comment: @ βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ : It is working fine now.Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have posted it as an answer. You can accept it to mark your post as solved.

Comment: Uh that's not a solution, that's a workaround. Open the same page in different browser tabs/windows in the same session and play around in each of them. You'll understand why that isn't a solution.

Comment: @BalusC : Then what is the exact solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void edit() throws IOException {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/employeeedit.jsf");
}
```

Your `edit` method above, redirects to a new view, that's when your `@ViewScoped` managed bean `EmployeeEdit` is destroyed. So, when it is instantiated again, the `tabIndex` is initialized to 0 (since 0 is the default value for `int`s in Java.)

As the name suggests `@ViewScoped` is good for one view, when want to some PPR on the same view. So, it is destroyed when you redirect to some other view.

In such a case, you can use `@SessionScoped`, which lasts as long as the session lasts.

Comment: When I put AJAX event="tabChange" listener is working. When I didnt change my tab, then the previous tab index is coming. This is because` `private int tabIndex; ` is not set to 0 the next time `EmployeeEdit.java)`.How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think you may not need to use `@SessionScoped` bean. In fact, it may be a big waste of resources if you don't reuse data in this bean very often.

I think you should keep your bean `@ViewScoped` and take advantage of `<f:param>`. You can try this:

```
<p:tabView id="myid" activeIndex="#{param.tabIndex}" >
    ...
</p:tabView>

<p:commandButton value="Edit" action="employeeedit" ajax="false">
   <f:param name="tabIndex" value="#{employeeEdit.tabIndex}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

This may save you some resources and you don't need the `edit` function just to redirect the user yo the edit page.

Comment: "In your redirect function, it seems to me that you are redirecting to the same edit page." No, he is actually redirecting from `view.jsf` to `edit.jsf`.